# How can I determine if my Intel CPU does throttle?

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature, throttling

I have a Dell M6600 Laptop with an Intel Core-i7 CPU, and it is becoming pretty loud and hot recently, and slows down. I suspect that the CPU gets very hot, and would like to see if the thermal throttling becomes active.

I know there are a lot of programs showing the current core temperature, but I haven't found one that displays if the CPU is currently throttling (thermal throttling) or not.

Do you know any?

Comment: Use a program that indicates the frequency of the CPU.  If the frequency drops below the base frequency of the CPU then the CPU is being throttled.  Of course just determine if your CPU is overheating, if its not overheating, then its throttling itself.

Answer (score 1):

The official one by Intel shows weather it is turbo-boosting or not (http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/intel_turbo_boost_technology_monitor.html)

I have noticed that just the difference of turbo boosting causes a *huge* difference in heat output. A trick I discovered to keep it from turbo boosting and heating up so much is to create a power plan in windows and set the maximum CPU level to 99%. This will allow it to function at it's base rating (2.3 ghz for me) and below, but not turbo boost, and therefore keep the cpu cool and keep it from throttling.